# Expectation of a chi-squared distribution

Tags: self-study, expected-value, chi-squared-distribution

I am to find out the value of this expectation : $$E \bigg(\frac{U^p}{U+V} \bigg),$$ where U $\sim$ $\chi^2_1$ and V $\sim$ $\chi^2_n$. U and V are independent.

Can anyone give me any hints about how to start this problem ?

Comment: Dwaipayan -- I would have asked you to add the tag if Jeremy had not added it already. Please read the `self-study` [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty. If you don't think it falls under the tag, please explain how the question arises.

Comment: Hint: Integrate it, changing variables from $(u,v)$ to $u=(r\cos(\theta))^2$ and $v=(r\sin(\theta))^2$.  The double integral will separate: the integral over $r$ evaluates to a Gamma function while the integral over $\theta$ evaluates to a Beta function.  You should obtain $\frac{2^p \Gamma \left(p+\frac{1}{2}\right)}{\sqrt{\pi } (n+2 p-1)}.$

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The PDFs are

$$f_U(u) = C(1)u^{-1/2} e^{-u/2}$$

and

$$f_V(v) = C(n)v^{n/2-1}e^{-v/2}$$

where

$$C(k) = \frac{1}{2^{k/2}\Gamma(\frac{k}{2})}$$

are the normalizing constants.  Use polar-like coordinates $u=(r\cos(\theta))^2$ and $v=(r\sin(\theta))^2$ to evaluate the expectation, after first computing

$$\eqalign{du\wedge dv &= (2 r \cos(\theta)^2 dr - 2r^2 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)d\theta)\wedge (2 r \sin(\theta)^2 dr + 2 r^2 \sin(\theta)\cos(\theta)d\theta) \\
&= 4r^3\sin(\theta)\cos(\theta) dr\wedge d\theta}$$

and

$$u+v = r^2(\cos(\theta)^2 + \sin(\theta)^2) = r^2,$$

so that (provided $n+2p \gt 1$) it splits into a Beta integral involving $\theta$ and a Gamma integral involving $r^2$ and a great deal of cancellation occurs:

$$\eqalign{\mathbb{E}\left(\frac{U^p}{U+V}\right) &= C(1)C(n)\int_0^\infty\int_0^\infty \frac{u^p}{u+v} u^{-1/2} v^{n/2-1} e^{-(u+v)/2}\, du\, dv,\\
&= 4C(1)C(n)\color{blue}{\int_0^{\pi/2}\sin(\theta)^{n-1}\cos(\theta)^{2p} d\theta}\color{red}{ \int_0^\infty r^{2p+n-2} e^{-r^2/2} dr} \\
&= 2^2 \frac{1}{2^{1/2}\Gamma(1/2)} \frac{1}{2^{n/2}\Gamma(n/2)} \color{blue}{\frac{\Gamma(n/2)\Gamma(p+1/2)}{2\Gamma(p+n/2-1/2)}}\; \color{red}{2^{p+n/2-3/2} \Gamma(p+n/2-1/2)} \\
&= \frac{2^p \Gamma(p+1/2)}{\sqrt{\pi}(n+2p-1)}.
}$$

Otherwise, if $n + 2p \le 1$, the integral diverges as $r\to 0$.