# Probability density function scalar-valued non-linear function of continuous random variables

Tags: probability, distributions

Is it possible to numerically calculate the probability density function for a scalar-valued function where each variable is independent and has a known distribution? For example in the simple case of $z=f(x,y)$:
$$
z=y*e^x
$$
if $x$ and $y$ have gaussian probability density functions, how can one calculate $Pz(Z)$?
For the 1-D case, transformation of variables is a good approach. Using the same example for 1-D i.e., $z=f(x)$:
$$
z=e^x
$$
We would have:
$$
Pz(Z)=Px(x)\left|\frac{dx}{dz}\right|
$$
But I'm not sure how to handle this for the case $z=f(x,y)$. I've seen some solutions out there for multiple-to-multiple change of variables, but these all involve using the determinant of a jacobian, which I don't believe is possible in this case as the jacobian would not be square. Thanks in advance for any help!

Comment: They all involve the generalization of the Jacobian; namely, the factors that appear in the wedge products.  A general answer is complicated because $f,$ when differentiable, is never one-to-one.  See https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/181708 for a worked example and search our site for [wedge product](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=+%22wedge+product%22) for more.

Comment: The for the resource, Whuber! I'm not too familiar with this sort of math, so sorry if this is a little basic, but doesn't that example work only for the expectation value? How would you go about doing this to calculate the probability at any given point along the probability vectors $Px(X)$ and $Py(Y)$ (in the example above) or $f_U(u)$ and $f_V(v)$ (in the linked problem)?

Comment: It works for any change of variables--it's far more general than probability calculations.